# linux + print the values in the same line

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, date, echo

when we print the variable data_data_dir , we get:

```
echo $data_data_dir
sdb sdc sdd sde sdf
```

but when we print it with the following approach the we get the value not in the same line

```
echo  "[`date +%d"/"%b"/"%G"-"%T`] $data_data_dir"
[27/Dec/2017-10:58:08] sdb
sdc
sdd
sde
sdf
```

while we want it as the following ( expected results )

```
[27/Dec/2017-10:58:08] sdb sdc sdd sde sdf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do not quote `$data_data_dir`

```
echo  "[`date +%d"/"%b"/"%G"-"%T`]" $data_data_dir
```

Answer (score 0):

I used below method to achieve the same

---

```
 l="sdb sdc sdd sde sdf";  y=`date +%d"/"%b"/"%G"-"%T`;  echo [$y] $l
```

---

l="sdb sdc sdd sde sdf" used double quotes at beginning and end of line so it will print in same row when it is called

output

```
[27/Dec/2017-21:50:43] sdb sdc sdd sde sdf
```

---